# Local variables not showing on CodeBlocks

Tags: c++, debugging, gdb, codeblocks

In the following code, all the variables disappears except for `c`. If I hover over the value of `c` in watches, I can see all the local variables.

```cpp
int x=61, i=0, sq=0, s1=0, s2=0;
char a='a';
```

[image: picture]

I have tried both TDM-GCC-64 and minGW, both show the same problem. How do I fix this?

Comment: The compiler may have optimized the variables away entirely..

Comment: Build a [mre] and someone familiar with the tools you are using stands a better chance of reproducing the behaviour and explaining it. B

Comment: Try changing `char c;` to `char c = 'a';`, does the problem go away?

Comment: @JesperJuhl how do I fix this then? The variables are present before the second loop, but disappears as soon as it enters the loop.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. It didn't fix the problem

Comment: Do the variables show up if you debug directly with `gdb`, without codeblocks?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I am not sure how to do that, but if I type `info local` in the debugger tab in the logs menu, I can see all the variables exactly as I see when I hover over `c`

Comment: looks like a less-than-perfectly working wrapper around gdb in codeblocks then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with gdb trying to print `CP65001` characters. The fix was to goto, settings->debugger->default->Debugger initialization commands and type,
`set charset UTF-8`. This fixed the problems for me.